# Hiibernate: @OrderColumn in @OneToMany causes an UPDATE after INSERT

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following POJOs for my db schema.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Quotes")
public class QuoteRequest
{
    public QuoteRequest(){}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "quote_request_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long QuoteRequestId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quoteRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "accidents_id")
    private Accidents[] accidents;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Accidents")
public class Accidents
{
    public Accidents()
    {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "accidents_id")
    private long AccidentId;


    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Float amount;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "quote_request_id", nullable = false)
    private QuoteRequest quoteRequest;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Because I'm using an array to store `Accidents[]` Hibernate is requiring me to add `@OrderColumn`. Adding this causes an update to be generated after insert that zeros out my `accidents_id`. The only way I found around that is to change Accidents[] to Set.

How can I keep Accidentsas an array and not have Hibernate force this 2nd update after the insert?

Comment: Have you tried creating explicit column for ordering purposes? I highly doubt that it is normal practice to use PK column as an `@OrderColumn`.

Comment: I have. Whatever I pick, there is an update statement being executed to set that value to 0. I don't understand why.